# How to check if entry is file or folder using Python's standard library zipfile?

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip, python-zipfile

I have a zip file and I need to check if a file is a folder or a file without extracting them. I could check it using `file_size` property of `infolist` if it is 0 but this is the same for a file with 0 size. So it is not useful.

I looked on the [ZIP specification](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) but that didn't helped much either.

How to check if entry is file or folder using Python's standard library zipfile?

Comment: Is there some reason not to use `os.path.isfile(path)` and `os.path.isdir(path)`?

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano I have a very good reason I don't want to extract the file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about checking if the filename ends with `/`?

Comment: I overlooked that and exactly that is the answer, simple. Thanks. +1&accept

Comment: can we use `os.sep` instead of `/`?

Comment: @Babu according to the ZIP file specification "All slashes MUST be forward slashes". So no :)